# Imagem chega nula no servidor

Tags: android, retrofit

Estou enviando dados usando o retrofit, observo toda a requisição até o fim e recebo o código 200 mais no lado do servidor a imagem chega nula, como estou enviando a imagem e textos o texto chega corretamente, sem problemas contudo a imagem não, já alterei o código, pesquisei olhei tutoriais, inicialmente eu estava enviando uma lista de imagens, mudei estou enviando apenas um mais este não é o problema meu servidor é em Java

Todo o processo começa obtendo imagem da camera, os dados da activity são gravados no banco SQLite e posteriormente pela ação do usuário ele chama um serviço que faz o envio do registro para o servidor.

Aqui a interface WebServiceApi.java

```
@Multipart
@POST("fw_file.rule")
public Call<WsViagemResponse> sendViagem3(
        @Part("metodo") RequestBody metodo,
        @Part("parametros") RequestBody parametro,
        @Part MultipartBody.Part images
);
```

aqui o código na classe responsável por transmitir os dados

```
MultipartBody.Part file1 = prepareFilePart("arquivo1.jpg", v.getFoto());
// Retrofit
WebServiceApi apiService = ApiClient
            .getClient(cURL)
            .create(WebServiceApi.class);

    Call<WsViagemResponse> call = apiService.sendViagem3(
            createPartFromString("fw_addViagem"),
            createPartFromString(parametros),
            file1
    );

@NonNull
private MultipartBody.Part prepareFilePart(String fileName, byte[] content) {

    RequestBody requestFile =
                   RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("image/*"), content);

    return MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("file", fileName, requestFile);
}

@NonNull
private RequestBody createPartFromString(String descriptionString) {
    return RequestBody.create(
            MediaType.parse(MULTIPART_FORM_DATA), descriptionString);
}
```

para as dependências

```
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.1.0'
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.7'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.1.0'
compile 'com.github.anshulagarwal06:Simplify-Permissions:v1'
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.3.1'
```

Não sei o que pode estar errado uma vez que no logcat eu vejo toda a requisição sendo feita

```
D/OkHttp: fw_addViagem
D/OkHttp: --55fa9778-7456-403f-be6b-48ab3c386c9b
D/OkHttp: Content-Disposition: form-data; name="parametros"
D/OkHttp: Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary
D/OkHttp: Content-Type: multipart/form-data; charset=utf-8
D/OkHttp: Content-Length: 82
D/OkHttp: 1|3|2|06/01/2017 17:38:55|01/02/1900 00:00:00|01/02/1900
D/OkHttp: --55fa9778-7456-403f-be6b-48ab3c386c9b
D/OkHttp: Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file";   filename="arquivo1.jpg"
D/OkHttp: Content-Type: image/*
D/OkHttp: Content-Length: 16053
```

vem depois deste log a imagem e no final

```
D/OkHttp: <-- 200 OK http://10.0.10.25:8082/webrun/fw_file.rule (111ms)
```

Answer (score 1):

O problema aqui tem a ver com os parâmetros do meu Servidor, ele espera três cujos nomes são: metodo, parametro e arquivo

A interface tem os três porém nela não nomeamos o ultimo

```
@Part MultipartBody.Part images
```

A solução esta no método prepareFilePart, onde antes eu tinha "file" devo trocar por "arquivo" casando com o parâmetro esperado

```
@NonNull
private MultipartBody.Part prepareFilePart(String fileName, byte[] content) {

        RequestBody requestFile =
               RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("image/*"), content);

        return MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("arquivo", fileName, requestFile);
    }
```